# Get the pull request that introduced a commit

Tags: github, github-api

In github, when I click on a commit, I can see the pull request that introduced it.

[image: commit with link to PR that introduced it]

You can see this commit was introduced by PR 15.

How can I get the associated pull request for a particular commit from the Github API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the #15 indicates the issue/PR number. If you have a commit sha it is possible to find the associated PR# using the GitHub search API (v3).

For example, suppose you have a commit sha - `7dd1bcf5f2f5eeed34cc2ec63053098fba302b6c`. To find the PR# from this sha, your query using the GitHub APi can look something like this- `https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=sha:7dd1bcf5f2f5eeed34cc2ec63053098fba302b6c`. From JSON response, the field 'number' represents the PR# (in this case 16).

Ref. [Search Issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues)